# A question I answered was migrated. Now I can't comment on the migrated post

Tags: support, migration, linked-accounts, superuser

I just answered [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/525211/how-to-crop-image-in-linux) on Stack Overflow. Suddenly the question was moved to superuser.com.

Now I want to add reply a comment from the person asking the question, so I created a new account at superuser.com, but how can I post comment when I do not have reputation at superuser.com?

Can I connect the two accounts?

Comment: @gamehelp16 So I have to create yet another account?

Comment: @Vering - Just log in on superuser with the same openid as you use for stackoverflow.

Comment: OK, I tried that but could not make it work, so created a new account with the same usename. I might have done something wrong...

Comment: @MartinSmith When I try this I get an error "Sorry, something just went wrong in Launchpad Login Service." Might it be because I created an account with the same user name?

Comment: If you login and associate your accounts, you automatically get `100` free rep points, which allows you to reply to the comments.

Comment: @Vering - A moderator might be able to have a look at your two accounts and see the issue.

Comment: @Vering you can use your stackexchange account to login to meta stackoverflow

Comment: @mellamokb I look for such an option. Where can I find it?

Comment: @mellamokb - Not in this case as the OP only has 24 rep on SO. 200 rep is required on one of the sites before the association bonus applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your [Super User account](https://superuser.com/users/183116/vering), the OpenID you've used there is StackID, not LaunchPad

[image]

I'd recommend you click on the "Add more logins" dialog that you get when you click on My Logins, and then proceed to login with your launchpad login **after** you logout of launchpad, and [StackID](http://openid.stackexchange.com/). Doing so should merge your accounts

Comment: Thank you Sathya! My accounts are connected now, but unfortunately I've lost all my reputation... Hmm.

Comment: @Vering that's because the accounts aren't still merged - I've flagged one of your posts to be merged by a Moderator

Comment: thank you! Now I have my reputation on Stackoverflow, but still cannot do anything on superuser.com (to where the question was migrated). Don't know if anything can be done...

Comment: @Vering I've gone ahead and associated the posts that were "lost" with your account. You should be all set!

Comment: Thanks @Aarthi! Vering, you should have full control over your posts.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help. Appreciate that you spend the time necessary to get things fixed.